# How to get the name from the id in select2 combo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, ui-select2

I have [`select2`](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) ComboBox the data is loaded by Ajax. I am trying to set the default value to the `select2` by reading the `id` from the input value (which is set on the server side) and set it to the `select2` programmatically.

I think I should implement the `initSelection()` function in a way to solve this issue.

Here is my code:

The HTML input is:

```
<input type="hidden" class="mySelect2" value="01" name="someName" />
```

```
The value "01" is set at the server
```

The JavaScript is:

```
$(".mySelect2").select2({
    ajax: {
        url:"data.php",
        dataType:"json",
        data:function(term, page) {
            return {
                query:term, page: page -1
            } ;
        },
        results:function(data, page) {
            return data  
        }
    }
});
```

I tried this but it did not work .

```
     $(".mySelect2").select2('val', '01');
```

And an error occured : "cannot call val() if `initSelection()` is not defined "

Comment: select2 is a javascript plugin this is is documentation  http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
        $(function(){
            $(".mySelect2").select2({
                ajax: {
                    url:"data.php",
                    dataType:"json",
                    data:function(term, page) {
                        return {
                            query:term, page: page -1
                        } ;
                    },
                    results:function(data, page) {
                        return data  
                    },

                }
            });
            $(".mySelect2").select2('data', {id:'01',text:'01'});
        })
```

HTML CODE

```
<input type="hidden" class="mySelect2" style="width:100px;" value="[{id:'01',text:'01'}]" name="someName" />
```

Comment: thanks 4 the answer but it is not what I want. I need to set the selected <name> by the <id> if it's possible .
In other word I need to guess the <name> from <id> and select it.

Comment: I mean <text> in place of <name>.I tried this: $(".mySelect2").select2('val', '01'); but there is error "initSelection is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

The general premise of initialising a default value in a select2 control using ajax can be solved using something like:

```
initSelection: function (element, callback) {
        var id = $(element).val();
        if (id !== "") {
        $.ajax("data.php", {
            data: {
                id: id // return a single item from your service
            },
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function (data) {
            var results = [];
            $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                results.push({
                    id: item.Id, // whatever your id field is
                    text: item.TextValue // whatever your text field is
                });
            });
            callback(results[0]);
        });
    }
}
```

I'm not a PHP person, but this should be standard across ajax requests.  The approach basically assumes you can return a single result as well as the list.

Comment: Does this means that I cannot set the selected item in select2 control locally from the data I have already initialized by `ajax` ? And I am obliged to send an ajax request in `initSelection` to get single item I already have in the pre-initialized data? I wonder if I can get the item from the pre-initialized data by `id`  in `initSelection` and `callback` it .

Comment: Looking at your code you haven't already loaded the data - it will be loaded lazily when you drop the select control. In general, it's better design to query for a single value (negligible payload) and if required get the rest of the data on demand.  You can make use of the select2 control's support for paged on demand loading too.